# How do I disable a main floor thermostat and add one in a basement suite?

Tags: thermostat

We are thinking of renting out the main floor of our home but don't want the tenant to have control of the only thermostat. Perhaps we could disable the one on the Main floor and add one to the basement suite.  What would this involve?

Comment: What type of heating system are you using? Does it include air conditioning?

Comment: Do you want to control the entire house from the basement suite or are you hoping to set the upstairs & basement separately?

Answer (score 1):

The thermostat wiring needs to be run to the location you want the thermostat or purchase a locking cover. Their are [wifi controlled](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HHE60CE) thermostats that you can install so it can be adjusted with your phone tons of option here I just grabbed one for an example.

Comment: +1 Leaving the thermostat where it is should be a priority as changing it to a different location (basement especially) may drastically change the way it works.